# IAuthenticationManager does not contain definition of GetExternalLoginInfoAsync, How do i fix this issue?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this method  and i am getting this line of error to it, please assist me.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl) {
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();//IAuthenticationManager does not contain definition of GetExternalLoginInfoAsync. Are you missing some assembly?
}
 private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;// HttpContext does not contain a definition of GetOwinContext. are you missing some assembly or directive.
            }
        }
```

NB:// For GetOwinContext i followed this link to install the package, the error is now gone, but im still left with the error for GetExternalLoginInfoAsync.
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5255999/Httpcontextbase-does-not-contain-a-definition-for

Comment: It's in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin namespace

Comment: @feihoa i already have this namespace. What can i do if i do have it? Must i have to install using NuGet command on VS?

Comment: Yep, try to install nuget package via package manager. It has the same name

Comment: @feihoa thanks mate, the error seem gone. I didn't know i was missing that correct assembly to that object.

Comment: @feihoa I am facing the same problem, `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync` does not belong to `AuthenticationManager`. I have  Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin NuGet package installed and the corresponding using, but it does not work. I am trying to retrieve user information from `FindAsync` method in a custom user store, after Google authentication was performed.